# Routing is serving JS files with HTML in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am created an AngularJS app and am creating a service that provides the user a link like `localhost:8080/sync/03afdbd66e7929b1` which they are supposed to share with people and will bring them to a form. However, after I setup the route to handle this request like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
            controller : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/about',
        {
            templateUrl : 'views/about.html',
            controller : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/begin',
        {
            templateUrl : 'views/sync.html',
            controller : 'syncCtrl'
        })
        .when('/sync/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'views/form.html',
            controller : 'formCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });

    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }

}]);
```

and create a view called `form.html`, then when I try to go to the link above, all of a sudden all of my JavaScript files are filled with my index.html and I have the following javascript errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < routes.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < controllers.js:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=syncIt&p1=Er…arjs.org%2F1.3.0-beta.9%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DsyncIt%0A%20%20%20%20...<omitted>...5) angular.js:3
```

This is because all of these .js files are now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>DaemonDeveloper</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <style>
        body, html {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background:#fff;
            font-family:verdana;
            color:#3DEB94;
        }
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
            color:inherit;
        }
        nav {
                position:relative;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                background:#fff;
                width:100%;
                min-width: 960px;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #app {
            min-width: 960px;
        }

        #nav-wrap {
            list-style: none;
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .nav-item {
            display:inline-block;


        }
        .nav-item > a {
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color:#3DEB94;
            font-size:22px;
            font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
            padding:15px 25px;
            display:inline-block;

        }
        .nav-item > a:hover {
            color:#fff;
            background:#3DEB94;
            cursor:pointer;
        }


        #banner {
            width:100%;
            text-align: left;
            background:#3DEB94;
            color:#fff;
        }
        #banner > h1 {
            font-size:72px;
            padding-left:50px;
            line-height:150px;
            font-weight:400;
            display:inline;
        }
        #banner > h2 {
            padding-left:200px;
            line-height: 150px;
            display:inline;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        }


        #step-list {
            width:100%;
            position:relative;
        }
        .step {
            width:100%;
            color:#fff;
        }
        .step:nth-child(odd) {
            background:#3DEB94;
            color:#fff;
        }
        .step:nth-child(even){
            background:#fff;
            color:#3DEB94;
        }

        .step-text {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 350px;
            font-size:60px;
            font-weight: 400;

        }
        .step-start {
            display:block;
            margin:100px auto;
            font-size:60px;
            background-color:#fff;
            color:#3DEB94;
            border:4px solid #3DEB94;
            padding:25px;
            border-radius:25px;
            -webkit-transition:background-color 1s;
            -webkit-transition:color 1s;

        }
        .step-start:hover {
            background-color:#3DEB94;
            color:#fff;
            border:4px solid #fff;
        }
        #sync-link {
            padding:35px 50px;
            background:#DEDEDE;
            margin:0 auto;
            border-radius: 12px;

            -moz-box-shadow:   inset 0 0 15px #adadad;
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #adadad;
             box-shadow:         inset 0 0 15px #adadad;
             color:#adadad;
        }

        .view {
            background:#fff;
            color:#3DEB94;
            width:960px;
            position: relative;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .xlarge-text {
            font-size:52px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding:62px 0;
        }
        .large-text {
            font-size: 42px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding:50px 0;
        }
        .med-text {
            font-size:32px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding:35px 0;
        }
        .center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .active {
            color:#fff !important;
            background:#3DEB94;
        }
        .invisible {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 1s;
        }
        .success {
            color:green;
        }
        .failure {
            color:red;
        }


        .input {
            padding:12px;
            font-size:22px;
            border-radius:8px;
            border: 3px solid #3DEB94;
        }
        input:focus, button:focus {
            outline:none;
        }
        .sync-btn {
            padding:12px;
            border:3px solid #3DEB94;
            font-size:22px;
            background:#fff;
            color:#3DEB94;
            border-radius:8px;
        }

        #identifier {
            margin-bottom:150px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="syncIt">
        <section id="banner">
            <h1>sync.it</h1>
            <h2>Test</h2>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul id="nav-wrap">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/begin">Begin</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="app" ng-view>

        </section>


            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.nav-item').click(function(){
                        $('.nav-item > a').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
                    })
                })
            </script>

            <script src="content/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="content/routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="content/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

There is some kind of weird routing going on here and I can't figure out why it is just this route and whether or not it is an Angular problem or a Node problem.

Comment: Is there a route handler in nodejs first which handles the /sync/id url?

Comment: Post your node.js routing code somewhere. It sounds like you're missing static assert serving middleware like `express.static()` or it's misconfigured.

Comment: ok here are my node routes http://pastebin.com/yySTEq6A. I tried to make it so that any non API calls just render the Angular app, which works for everything else except this route

Comment: You don't have a static route in your node configuration for the content/* route. Therefore the request for the javascript files is falling through to the default route, and returning index.html for each of them.

Comment: Why does it work completely fine for every other route then?

Comment: Given that, I suspect your problem is because the path to your javascript files is relative "content/..." instead of "/content/..."  When you try to access that /sync URL directly (other than a file in the root), your request to the node server for "content/app.js" is relative to the "/sync" path, which is causing the problem.

Comment: I found that after trying to go to `localhost:8080/sync/123`, my HTML file contains `<script>` tags that are trying to access JS files like `localhost:8080/sync/content/js/app.js` instead of just `localhost:8080/content/js/app.js` which is what it should be

Comment: right, that is what I said in comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not really sure how I can fix this. Do you know? I'm new express and am not sure what to do to serve static pages like you said.

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment

Comment: Was more explict. See the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54165/discussion-between-robm-and-matt-hintzke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your script references are relative. When you directly access a /sync url (not dynamically on the client using Angular), the request for content/app.js is falling to the node config for index.html.  With this config, the dynamic routing would be fine, because the path works when you initially access any file in the root, such as /index.html.

Change your script references to be relative to the root.

```
        <script src="/content/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/content/routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/content/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And change your Angular route template path to start with '/', like this:

```
    .when('/sync/:id', {
        templateUrl : '/views/form.html',
        controller : 'formCtrl'
    })
```

Comment: After I did change that, now my site is in an infinite loop of requests for the JS files and the page just crashes.

Comment: looping caused by relative path that doesn't start with '/' in your angular routing. Updating the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The way your server is written, the route responds to a querystring, not a parameter, so it's not being triggered on your API call. `/sync?nameId=03afdbd66e7929b1` for example. You need to change:

```
app.get('/api/sync', function(req, res){){
    var nameId = req.query.nameId;
```

to this:

```
app.get('/api/sync/:nameId', function(req, res){){
    var nameId = req.params.nameId;
```

Comment: my `app.get('/api/sync')` is a completely different thing then what I am trying to do. That is an API call. The `/sync/03afdbd66e7929b1` is supposed to just change the Angular view